# Why don't work regexp positive lookahead in Symfony routes?

Tags: regex, symfony

The `/en(?=/)demo/` regexp pattern must match with `/en/demo/` URI, but it doesn't work in Symfony route.

The full example code of route is:

```
demo:
    pattern:  /{_locale}demo/
    defaults: { _controller: BWMainBundle:Demo:index }
    requirements:
        _locale: 'en(?=/)'
```

Why does not work regexp positive lookahead in Symfony 2?

Comment: While this is not related to your problem, but I'll suggest you to try [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle) which works wonderfully well for setting the correct routes according to the locale selected.

Comment: @VisioN Thanks for advice! I try to learn it bundle, maybe it will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony doesn't allow lookarounds in the requirements: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/10548 The reason is that only the part of the "{_locale}" is matched to the regex, not everything around it.

I'm also wondering why you would want it this way? In case you want an optional locale parameter, you should create 2 routes and bind them to the same controller:

```
demo_multilang:
    pattern:  /{_locale}/demo/
    defaults: { _controller: BWMainBundle:Demo:index }
    requirements:
        _locale: 'en'

demo:
    pattern:  /demo/
    defaults: { _controller: BWMainBundle:Demo:index, _locale: en }
    requirements:
        _locale: 'en'
```

This will be solved when https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5424 is finally implemented.

Comment: Won't it match `//demo/` on default `_locale`?

Comment: @VisioN hmm, it seems like it doesn't match anything at all. So you have to create 2 routes and bind them to the same controller. Edited my post. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! It's a good solution, but I want to do the same without second route. The problem is that I need every my route duplicate with and without locale. Now I have near 50 routes, so it will be 100 when I duplicate them :(

Comment: The are no another way for do not duplicate the route?

Comment: @Victor unfortunately, Symfony currently only supports optional parameters at the end of a URL. I think you can create your own matcher to match the route with and without the locale part.